# Negative lookup behind not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I don't want to extract values if it comes after up to ex.

up to 12 gb ->

12 gb -> 12 gb

regex -> `(?i)(?<!up\s{1}to\s{1})([0-9]{1,})\s*(GB|MB|KB)`

Input -> `up to 12 gb output` -> `2 gb` (not expected)

```
      up to 1 gb output ->        (expected)
```

I am not able to findout how it gets 2 gb for 1st input

Comment: (OT: `{1}` is entirely superfluous, and `+` is the same as `{1,}` but more commonly used and easier to read.)

Comment: You can use: `(?i)(?<!up\sto\s)\b\d+\s*[GMK]B`

Comment: Use `(?i)\b(?<!\bup\sto\s)\d+\s*[GMK]B`

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat It seems clear to me.  Malav is confused about why the regexp that they've given matches `2` but not `12` from `up to 12 gb`.

Comment: Frankly, I'm confused too.  I would have expected the first capture group to match `12` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`(?i)(?<!up\s{1}to\s{1})([0-9]{1,})\s*(GB|MB|KB)` regex matches `2 gb` in `12 gb`](https://regex101.com/r/GlHO2v/2) because the lookbehind fails the match at the `1` char position (since it is preceded with `up to` , but, since the regex engine goes on to find matches inside the string, it matches at the next position, after `1`.

You may "anchor" the match at a word boundary (with `\b`), or at a positon after a non-digit (`(?<![0-9])`), e.g. `(?i)\b(?<!\bup\sto\s)\d+\s*[GMK]B`, but it will not work in case there is 0 or more spaces between the `up to` and the number.

Use a [***constrained width lookbehind***](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width) that allows using `{min,max)` limiting quantifiers inside lookbehinds:

```
String pat = "(?i)\\b(?<!\\bup\\s{0,100}to\\s{0,100})\\d+\\s*[GMK]B\\b";
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/QpFOeY):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("up to 1 gb output", "up to 1gb output", "up   to1 gb output", "1 gb output");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b(?<!\\bup\\s{0,100}to\\s{0,100})\\d+\\s*[GMK]B\\b");
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(str + ": " + m.group(0));
    }
}
```

Output

```
1 gb output: 1 gb
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `\\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\\bup\\s{0,100}to\\s{0,100})` - immediately to the left of the current location, there can't be a whole word `up` followed with 0 to 100 whitespaces, then `to`, then again 0 to 100 whitespaces
- `\\d+` - 1+ digits  (replace with `\\d[\\d.]*` to match floats as well)
  `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `[GMK]B` - `GB`, `MB` or `KB`
- `\\b` - word boundary.

NOTE: putting `\b` word boundary at the start of the pattern, you make it more efficient since there is no need checking the whole lookbehind pattern before testing for the word boundary.

Comment: thank you so much for detailed explanation. But i get this when using it. It wont accept {m, n}
{0,100} A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width

Comment: @Malav See https://ideone.com/QpFOeY. Where do you see that warning? Even Java regex online testers says [it is OK](http://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyegmvyr).

Comment: @Malav Do you realize you are testing a Java regex in a **PCRE** tester? Why??? Please do not mix regex flavors. If you want it to work in Java, use Java compatible tools.

Comment: @Malav Again, see http://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyyegmvyr if you like online regex testers.

Comment: Was not aware of that. I do use lot of regex at my work. And try validate those at regex101.com before writing code. You meant it should work fine when i write code.

Comment: @Malav I have written the code you may just copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex with a negative lookbehind and word boundary:

```
(?i)(?<!up\sto\s)\b\d+\s*[GMK]B
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7AQbTm/1)

`\b` is important here to make sure lookbehind expression is not asserted before 1 or more digits.

Also remember that `\s{1}` is same as `\s`.

Comment: If there are 2 spaces before the number, it will still extract the number.

Comment: @anubhava But lookuo behind works with fixed width. If i have multiple spaces/zero space after 'up'/ 'to' how should i handle it

Comment: @Malav: You didn't mention requirement about multiple spaces in your question and your regex has `(?<!up\s{1}to\s{1})` which means single space only.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. But basic case was not working for me so posted that.

Comment: It is easier to replace all multiple spaces with a single and then apply this regex e.g. `str = str.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");`